# Flatten a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{"average": 2, "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"average": 3, "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"average": 9, "day": "2022-01-03", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"sum": 13,    "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"sum": 15,    "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"sum": 0,     "day": "2022-01-03", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"average": 1, "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2},
        {"average": 3, "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2},
        {"sum":     9, "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2},
        {"sum":     8, "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2}]
```

I want my output as:

```
output = [{"name": "joe", "employee_id": 1, "day": "2022-01-01", "average": 2, "sum": 13},
          {"name": "joe", "employee_id": 1, "day": "2022-01-02", "average": 3, "sum": 15},
          {"name": "joe", "employee_id": 1, "day": "2022-01-03", "average": 9, "sum": 0},
          {"name": "bob", "employee_id": 2, "day": "2022-01-01", "average": 1, "sum": 9},
          {"name": "bob", "employee_id": 2, "day": "2022-01-02", "average": 3, "sum": 8}]
```

The goal is that the output values are put together by day, name, and employee_id.

I've tried:

```
output = {}
for item in data:
    if item["day"] not in output:
        output[item["day"]] = item
    else:
        output[item["day"]].update(item)
print(list(output.values()))
```

This works in getting the "average" and "sum" and "date" together, but it ends up not including all of the employees and their IDs.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your desired output doesn't look to have a valid format.  Would you edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict` with `dict`. Here, take the value of `'day'` and `'name'` of each dictionary as the key:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> defdict = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for mp in data:
...     defdict[mp['day'], mp['name']].update(mp)
...
>>> keys = ('name', 'employee_id', 'day', 'average', 'sum')
>>> [{k: mp[k] for k in keys} for mp in defdict.values()]
[{'name': 'joe', 'employee_id': 1, 'day': '2022-01-01', 'average': 2, 'sum': 13},
 {'name': 'joe', 'employee_id': 1, 'day': '2022-01-02', 'average': 3, 'sum': 15},
 {'name': 'joe', 'employee_id': 1, 'day': '2022-01-03', 'average': 9, 'sum': 0},
 {'name': 'bob', 'employee_id': 2, 'day': '2022-01-01', 'average': 1, 'sum': 9},
 {'name': 'bob', 'employee_id': 2, 'day': '2022-01-02', 'average': 3, 'sum': 8}]
```

For 150w pieces of data, the performance of this solution is still better than that of pandas (at least when converting data into `DataFrame`, the for loop has completed the work):

```
In [451]: random.seed(0)
     ...: names = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=random.randrange(3, 7))) for _ in range(10000)]
     ...: dates = [str(datetime.date(2022, i, j)) for i in range(7, 10) for j in range(1, 31)]
     ...: keys = ['sum', 'average']
     ...:
     ...: data = [{k: random.randrange(10), 'day': date, 'name': name, 'employee_id': i}
     ...:         for i, name in enumerate(names, 1)
     ...:         for date in sorted(random.sample(dates, random.randrange(60, 90)))
     ...:         for k in keys]
     ...:

In [452]: len(data)
Out[452]: 1492286

In [453]: %%timeit
     ...: defdict = defaultdict(dict)
     ...: for mp in data:
     ...:     defdict[mp['day'], mp['name']].update(mp)
     ...: keys = ('name', 'employee_id', 'day', 'average', 'sum')
     ...: [{k: mp[k] for k in keys} for mp in defdict.values()]
     ...:
     ...:
926 ms ± 6.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [454]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
     ...: pd.merge(df.loc[df['average'].notna()][[ 'name','day','employee_id','average']],
     ...:          df.loc[df['sum'].notna()][['name','day','employee_id','sum']],
     ...:          how='outer'
     ...: ).to_dict(orient= 'records')
     ...:
     ...:
3.58 s ± 19.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [455]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(data)
1.26 s ± 17.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Why not just `output = list(defdict.values())`?

Comment: @ekhumoro I am not sure if the order of key value pairs in the expected output is necessary.

Comment: @MechanicPig ended up using yours. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

here is one way to do it

```
# filter using loc where average is not null and where sum is not null, as two separate frame
# merge the two DF
#finally, output as a dict of orient record

pd.merge(df.loc[df['average'].notna()][[ 'name','day','employee_id','average']],
         df.loc[df['sum'].notna()][['name','day','employee_id','sum']],
         how='outer'
).to_dict(orient= 'records')
```

```
[{'name': 'joe',
  'day': '2022-01-01',
  'employee_id': 1,
  'average': 2.0,
  'sum': 13.0},
 {'name': 'joe',
  'day': '2022-01-02',
  'employee_id': 1,
  'average': 3.0,
  'sum': 15.0},
 {'name': 'joe',
  'day': '2022-01-03',
  'employee_id': 1,
  'average': 9.0,
  'sum': 0.0},
 {'name': 'bob',
  'day': '2022-01-01',
  'employee_id': 2,
  'average': 1.0,
  'sum': 9.0},
 {'name': 'bob',
  'day': '2022-01-02',
  'employee_id': 2,
  'average': 3.0,
  'sum': 8.0}]
```

Comment: At least in the current example, the execution time of your solution is at the millisecond level and the for loop is at the microsecond level (perhaps because the example is small). Do you have a larger example to let me verify that Pandas can work better?

Comment: I don’t have an example , though if you search, you’ll find plenty of example and details.

Comment: This means that "the FOR loop is way way slow in performance when compared with vectorized approach" only comes from your intuition. Your operation contains many unnecessary calculations, so vectorization does not bring good advantages. I tested with data of 50w random elements, and the Pandas solution is still 3 to 4 times slower than the for loop.

Comment: @MechanicPig, i stand incorrect in my assertion it seems. I concede. you put in a good effort. Regards

Answer (score 1):

From the description given the combination "day', "name", "employee_id" acts like a unique combination to which the other two fields should be added. Each incoming dictionary has these and we can use them as a key into a new dictionary, but we need to convert them to something hashable like a json string which we need to produce with sorting to make them unique..

```
from json import dumps

data = [{"average": 2, "day": "2022-01-01",  "employee_id": 1, "name": "joe"},
        {"average": 3, "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"average": 9, "day": "2022-01-03", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"sum": 13,    "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"sum": 15,    "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"sum": 0,     "day": "2022-01-03", "name": "joe", "employee_id": 1},
        {"average": 1, "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2},
        {"average": 3, "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2},
        {"sum":     9, "day": "2022-01-01", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2},
        {"sum":     8, "day": "2022-01-02", "name": "bob", "employee_id": 2}]

flattend_employee_summaries = dict()

for employee_summary in data:
    
    
    key = employee_summary.copy()
        
    if "average" in key:
        del key["average"]
        if dumps(key, sort_keys=True) not in flattend_employee_summaries:
            flattend_employee_summaries[dumps(key, sort_keys=True)] = employee_summary.copy()
        else:
            flattend_employee_summaries[dumps(key, sort_keys=True)]["average"] = employee_summary["average"]
            
    if "sum" in key:
        del key["sum"]
        if dumps(key, sort_keys=True) not in flattend_employee_summaries:
            flattend_employee_summaries[dumps(key, sort_keys=True)] = employee_summary.copy()
        else:
            flattend_employee_summaries[dumps(key, sort_keys=True)]["sum"] = employee_summary["sum"]
        
flattend_employee_summaries = [ summary for summary  in flattend_employee_summaries.values()]
          
print(f'{flattend_employee_summaries=}')
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronald van Elburg

Answer (score 1):

It has been answered, and I suspect this is the long way of repeating Mechanic Pig's solution which I'd recommend. For all of the solutions, I believe we are assuming there is only one average record per employee/day.

```
employees = dict()
for data_row in data:
    if data_row['employee_id'] not in employees:
        
        employees[data_row['employee_id']] = {data_row['day']: {'name':data_row.get('name', 0),
                                                                'average': data_row.get('average', 0), 
                                                                'sum': data_row.get('sum',0) 
                                                              } 
                                            }
    else:
        data_row_day = data_row['day']
        
        if data_row['day'] not in employees[data_row['employee_id']]:
            employees[data_row['employee_id']][data_row_day] = {'name':data_row.get('name', 0),
                                                                'average': data_row.get('average', 0), 
                                                                'sum': data_row.get('sum', 0) 
                                                              }
        else:
            current_sum = employees[data_row['employee_id']][data_row_day].get('sum',0)
            employees[data_row['employee_id']][data_row_day].update({'sum': current_sum + data_row.get('sum', 0) })

employee_output = list()
for employee_id, employee_dates in employees.items():
    for employee_date, employee_details in employee_dates.items():
        employee_output.append({"name": employee_details['name'],
                                "employee_id": employee_id,
                                "day": employee_date,
                                "average": employee_details['average'],
                                "sum":  employee_details['sum'],
                               })
```

`employee_output` would then contain:

```
[{'name': 'joe',
  'employee_id': 1,
  'day': '2022-01-01',
  'average': 2,
  'sum': 13},
 {'name': 'joe',
  'employee_id': 1,
  'day': '2022-01-02',
  'average': 3,
  'sum': 15},
 {'name': 'joe',
  'employee_id': 1,
  'day': '2022-01-03',
  'average': 9,
  'sum': 0},
 {'name': 'bob',
  'employee_id': 2,
  'day': '2022-01-01',
  'average': 1,
  'sum': 9},
 {'name': 'bob',
  'employee_id': 2,
  'day': '2022-01-02',
  'average': 3,
  'sum': 8}]
```